# Why is this SQL Server geometry query returning no geometry?

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I'm querying SQL Server 2017 for the point on a geometry line that is closest to a given point. The following works well for some data, not others. I can't understand the inconsistency.

```
declare @line geometry = 'LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)' 
declare @p1 geometry = 'POINT(3 2)'
declare @p2 geometry = 'POINT(3 1)'

select @p1.STBuffer(@p1.STDistance(@line)).STIntersection(@line).ToString()
select @p2.STBuffer(@p2.STDistance(@line)).STIntersection(@line).ToString()
```

The result for p1 is `POINT (2.500000 2.499999)` as expected.
The result for p2 is `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY` and I wonder why. There's nothing really different about the points.

[image]

Comment: I'm no geometry person but I find it interesting that `(3 0.9)` and `(3 1.1)` and `(3 1.000000000001)` also produce results but `(3 1.0000000000001)` and `(1 3)` fail. There must be something about 1 (or approaching 1) explicitly?

Comment: Extend the `LINESTRING` to `30 30` and you'll get results again. I do not offer this as an explanation. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatial type coordinates and the results of distance calculations are all floating point numbers, not exact real numbers.  And so when comparing you have to test with some tolerance for rounding and truncation differences at the limits of floating point accuracy.

So if you buffer with a small tolerance this works fine:

```
declare @line geometry = 'LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)' 
declare @p1 geometry = 'POINT(3 2)'
declare @p2 geometry = 'POINT(3 1)'

select @p1.STBuffer(1.0000000001*@p1.STDistance(@line)).STIntersection(@line).ToString()
select @p2.STBuffer(1.0000000001*@p2.STDistance(@line)).STIntersection(@line).ToString()
```

This is essentially the same as

```
select 'true' where 2 = power(sqrt(2),2)
```

quite literally as STDistance for geometry points is `sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-x2)^2)`

Comment: But this still seems like an obscure tribal knowledge thing and perhaps the methods should account for that and correct? Having to multiply every input value by `1.0000000001` is awkward, and what if that actually pushes a value (like `0.9999`) into a value that offsets the tolerance and fails again?

Comment: This is just a 2-D analog of ordinary floating point calculation and comparison, which can be a pain.

Comment: This is a particularly clear and concise answer. Thank you David.